# What does 何だって mean in this case?

Tags: translation, words

I was translating this song ([full lyrics here](https://www5.atwiki.jp/hmiku/pages/37091.html)) and I had trouble with the third line in this phrase (the rest are there for context)

> ああやってこうやって
> どうしようもないと思った
> 結局は何だって
> 才能が肝心なんだ

I was confused since 結局は何だって seemed to go by itself, but I don't really understand how it could. I was thinking it was just, "In the end, anything" which would go with the "I thought there's no other way;" that is, the speaker didn't know what to do, so they just did anything. I thought perhaps it could go with the next line, i.e. "In the end, having any talent is crucial," though I thought that was even less supported by the lyrics. I feel like I'm reaching with either interpretation, though.

How is 結局は何だって translated in this context?

Answer (score 4):

> 結局{けっきょく}は何{なん}だって
>
> 才能{さいのう}が肝心{かんじん}なんだ

First of all, these two lines constitute one sentence, not the first line by itself.

「だって」 here means 「でも」 or 「であっても」.

Thus, 「何だって」 means "whatever it is", "in/for anything", etc.

> "After all, whatever it is, talent is essential/important/crucial"